# Rename symbols in web assembly binary file

Tags: c, llvm, rename, webassembly, emscripten

I need a way to rename certain symbols in a WebAssembly binary archive file that were compiled from C files by emscripten.
When using gcc I can use the `objcopy --redefine-sym` command, but that gives me `objcopy: libname.bc: file format not recognized`
I also tried `llvm-objcopy`, but that gave me `llvm-objcopy: error: unsupported object file format`
Running `llvm-nm` did work on it however.
Running `file` gives `libname.bc: WebAssembly (wasm) binary module version 0x1 (MVP)`

Answer (score 1):

tldr; I'm not sure there is any easy way to do this today.

Renaming in source code and recompiling is the only way I can think of doing this, and you probably have some reason why you can't do that?

Support for WebAssembly in llvm-objcopy is only partial, and was only added recently: https://reviews.llvm.org/D70970.   So some parts of objcopy maybe work with but you would need llvm 11.

However I don't believe `--redefine-sym` is implemented yet, even on tip of tree.

If this was a normal WebAssembly binary you could just convert it to wat, edit it, and convert it back, but sadly with wasm object files that are extra custom sections that do not survive round trips.

Answer (score 1):

You have the change the names in the export section

https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#binary-exportsec

but if binary editing is to hard then translate your wasm into wabt then you can make the change with text editor and convert back from wabt into wasm